# Creating a co-occurrence matrix with counts of string pairs in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file, which I would like to convert to a co-occurrence matrix. I already split the file into tokens, and use combinations to get a list o word pairs and their counts. I do it like this:

```
val logData = sc.textFile(input_file, 2).cache()
val tokens = logData.map(_.split(" ").toList)
val coo = tokens.flatMap(_.combinations(2)).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

and I get the following output:

```
(List(garb, personae),1)
(List(chasm, dream),3)
(List(grandfathers, adulthood),1)
(List(dr, till),2)
(List(those, winds),1)
```

Now, I would like to convert it into a sparse matrix, with all unique words as rows and columns, and the count as values. Something like this:

```
          garb personae chasm dream ...
garb      0    1        0     0
personae  1    0        0     0
chasm     0    0        0     3
dream     0    0        3     0
...
```

As I understand, I could convert my strings into indices first, and use Spark's mllib to create a coordinate matrix. However, after researching the documentation, I'm pretty stuck and can't get anywhere with this.

Comment: you can [use `SparseMatrix.fomCOO`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/SparseMatrix.html#fromCOO(int,%20int,%20scala.collection.Iterable)) function to generate a sparse matrix, after transform your words to indices